# @WebFluxTest with Apache Freemarker fails

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-webflux

I am using Spring Boot 2.0 with Spring WebFlux and Apache Freemarker,

I have controller like following:

```
@Controller
public class ArticleController {

    @GetMapping("/new")
    public String newArticle() {
        return "article/new";
    }

}
```

It works fine when the application is started and `/new` endpoint is hit with a browser. But the following `@WebFluxTest` fails.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebFluxTest(ArticleController.class)
public class ArticleControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    public void getNew() {
        webTestClient.get().uri("/new").accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML).exchange().expectStatus().isOk();
    }
}
```

With the following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve view with name 'article/new'.
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.view.ViewResolutionResultHandler.lambda$resolveViews$3(ViewResolutionResultHandler.java:277) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:107) [reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1069) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoBufferAllSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:117) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:349) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onComplete(FluxConcatMap.java:265) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:125) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:111) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList.subscribe(MonoCollectList.java:59) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:1626) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:1440) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1314) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1069) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1069) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenAcceptInner.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:290) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:1626) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenAcceptInner.onSubscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:279) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:161) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:148) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekFuseable.subscribe(MonoPeekFuseable.java:74) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:271) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:803) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:115) [reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:1626) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:156) [reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:1440) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1314) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90) [reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:418) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:210) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:128) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:167) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:3188) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3074) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3041) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3013) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.HttpHandlerConnector.lambda$connect$1(HttpHandlerConnector.java:89) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.mock.http.client.reactive.MockClientHttpRequest.lambda$null$2(MockClientHttpRequest.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatIterable$ConcatIterableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatIterable.java:141) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatIterable.subscribe(FluxConcatIterable.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSourceFlux.subscribe(MonoSourceFlux.java:47) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:3188) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3074) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3041) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3013) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.HttpHandlerConnector.connect(HttpHandlerConnector.java:100) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WiretapConnector.connect(WiretapConnector.java:73) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.exchange(ExchangeFunctions.java:79) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.exchange(DefaultWebClient.java:325) ~[spring-webflux-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.DefaultWebTestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.exchange(DefaultWebTestClient.java:282) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.packtpub.springboot2blog.controller.ArticleControllerTest.getNewArticlePage_ShouldReturnNewArticlePage(ArticleControllerTest.java:30) ~[test-classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) ~[spring-test-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) ~[junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
```

Any hints on how to test this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but using Thymeleaf. I forgot to add the following annotation to my test class:

```
@Import({ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.class})
```

This will configure a view resolver. On Spring Boot 2.0.5, there is a similar class for FreeMarker, so you can try adding it to your test class:

```
@Import({FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration.class})
```